# Memory leak vs Zombie - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, zombie-process

My iPhone app is either crashing due to to a zombie, or leaking memory.. I've narrowed it down to 3 lines of code and can reliably get one of the two things to happen by commenting/uncommenting the code. The bugs occur when navigation between a list of results (tableView) and a details page containing a map and a few labels, memory leak happens the first time I navigation from the map back to the list of results, the zombie occurs after maybe 5/6 times navigating to different results and back.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface ResDetailsPageVC : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>  {

UISegmentedControl *mapTypeSwitcher;
MKMapView *mapView;      

UILabel *nameLabel;
UIButton *addressLabel;
UILabel *telephoneLabel;

NSString *address;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapTypeSwitcher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *addressLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *telephoneLabel;


- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged;
- (IBAction)callButtonClick;
- (IBAction)addressClick;

- (void) callNumber;

@end






@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize mapTypeSwitcher;

@synthesize nameLabel, addressLabel, telephoneLabel;

- (void)dealloc {

// if these lines are commented out - memory leak
// if not - zombie?!
/*self.telephoneLabel = nil;
self.addressLabel = nil;
self.nameLabel = nil;*/
self.mapView = nil;
self.mapTypeSwitcher = nil;

[super dealloc];

}
```

Comment: Did you put the retains in there? Because IBOutlets are links to object in a xib, so they don't need to be retained. Usually they are `assign`ed or in the case of ARC code `__unsafe_unretained` or `weak`.

Comment: I tried changing the properties to (nonatomic, assign) and then not deallocating or setting them to nil in dealloc but still get the zombie.

Comment: You keep saying you have zombies - that usually gives you more information, such as what object is sending the messages.

Comment: Found the problem - Interestingly it was code for my map annotation found at http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/ which was causing the crash. Didn't like [title release] for whatever reason.. Replaced the code with a cut down version of the code at http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial - all memory leaks, zombies and other nasty things gone!

Comment: That implementation leaks the title and subtitle. I think you're program has problems other than the memory management in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere some other piece of code is using the same object whose address is stored in one of those three properties, but that other piece of code has not properly retained the object.

Comment: Some other piece of code is using the UILabel object? Or is it the object I am using to set the label's value (this comes from an NSDictionary, originally retrieved from a JSON request)

Comment: It would have to be some sort of reference to the UILabel itself.  Do you reference the value in the UILabel from another class?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this to you:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[telephoneLabel release]; telephoneLabel = nil;
[addressLabel release]; addressLabel = nil;
....

[super dealloc];
}
```